# Why is a decorator triggered every time a function is decorated, and not when the decorated function is called?

Tags: python, python-decorators

In the following piece of code, why is `ls1` updated every time we decorate a function (e.g. when we decorate the function `api4`) but not every time we call the specific function?

```
ls1=[]

def register_usage(f):
    ls1.append((datetime.today(), f.__name__))
    return f

@register_usage
def api4():
    return 'api4'
```

Comment: Because the decorator returns the original function, which doesn't update `ls1` when called.

Answer (score 4):

Because that's how decorators work.

When you write:

```
@register_usage
def api4():
  ...
```

That is exactly equivalent to:

```
def orig_api4():
  pass

api4 = register_usage(orig_api4)
```

That is, the decorator receives the decorated function as an argument and returns a new function, which from that point replaces the original function. This all happens at function definition time.

When you call the decorated function, you're just calling whatever function was returned by the decorator.

Answer (score 4):

To make a decorator that does some work every time the function is called, you need to create and return an inner function.

```
ls1=[]

def register_usage(f):
    def impl():
        ls1.append((datetime.today(), f.__name__))
        return f()
    return impl

@register_usage
def api4():
    return 'api4'
```

Now `api4()` will actually call `impl()`, which appends to your global list and then delegates to the *original* `api4`.

Answer (score 0):

A decorator's purpose is to return a "decorated function" (i.e. a modified version of the function that follows the decoration).  In order to do that, the code in it needs to be executed on each function that it decorates.

What is only executed when your function is called, is the decorated version that is returned by the decorator's execution.  Note that the return value of each use of the decorator is a different function each of them base on the specific function following the @decorator.